# How to attach a suffix to `.value` when using `pivot_longer()` and `names_pattern`

Tags: r, tidyr

I would like to use `pivot_longer()` from {tidyr} with `names_pattern` to convert my data to long format **while** keeping the prefix string from one of the pattern matches in the column names.

This seems counter-intuitive, but I want to convert to long format before applying data dictionary cleaning steps, which requires the original column names.

#### Set-up

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

d <- tibble(id = 1,
            other_var = "foo",
            suffix_t1_value1 = "a",
            suffix_t1_value2 = "b",
            suffix_t2_value1 = "c",
            suffix_t2_value2 = "d")
```

#### What I've done

```
> pivot_longer(d,
               starts_with("suffix"),
               names_pattern = "suffix_t(1|2)_(.*)",
               names_to = c("rep", ".value"))

# A tibble: 2 x 5
     id other_var rep   value1 value2
  <dbl> <chr>     <chr> <chr>  <chr> 
1     1 foo       1     a      b     
2     1 foo       2     c      d
```

#### Desired output

```
# A tibble: 2 x 5
     id other_var rep   suffix_t1_value1 suffix_t1_value2
  <dbl> <chr>     <chr> <chr>            <chr>           
1     1 foo       1     a                b               
2     1 foo       2     c                d
```

#### What I've tried

##### Attempt 1

```
> pivot_longer(d,
               starts_with("suffix"),
               names_pattern = "suffix_t(1|2)_(.*)",
               names_to = c("rep", "suffix_t1_{.value}"))
```

##### Attempt 2

```
> pivot_longer(d,
               starts_with("suffix"),
               names_pattern = "suffix_t(1|2)_(.*)",
               names_to = c("rep", paste0("suffix_t1_", ".value")))
```

Answer (score 3):

I assume you want to do it in one step within `pivot_longer`. I haven't figured out yet, if thats possible, but if a two step process would be ok, then the approach below should work:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

d %>% pivot_longer(starts_with("suffix"),
                   names_pattern = "suffix_t(1|2)_(.*)",
                   names_to = c("rep", ".value")
             ) %>% 
  rename_with(~ gsub("(.*)", "suffix_t1_\\1", .x),
              starts_with("value"))

#> # A tibble: 2 x 5
#>      id other_var rep   suffix_t1_value1 suffix_t1_value2
#>   <dbl> <chr>     <chr> <chr>            <chr>           
#> 1     1 foo       1     a                b               
#> 2     1 foo       2     c                d
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

---

**Update**

After digging into `pivot_longer` a bit, I don't think that it is possible to access `.value` within `paste` and also glue syntax `{.value}` does not seem to be supported.

However, {tidyr} offers the building blocks for pivoting with `build_longer_spec` which allows us the create our own `my_pivot_longer` function where we can include a `names_fn` argument which will apply a function to the new column names, and here we could use `gsub` to add a prefix or suffix.

```r
my_pivot_longer <- function(data,
                            cols,
                            names_to = "name",
                            names_pattern = NULL,
                            names_fn = NULL) {
  
  spec <- build_longer_spec(data,
                            cols,
                            names_pattern = names_pattern,
                            names_to = names_to)

  if (!is.null(names_fn)) {
    fn <- rlang::as_function(names_fn)
    spec$.value <-  fn(spec$.value)
  }
  
  pivot_longer_spec(data, spec)
    
}

d %>% 
  my_pivot_longer(starts_with("suffix"),
                  names_pattern = "suffix_t(1|2)_(.*)",
                  names_to = c("rep", ".value"),
                  names_fn = ~ gsub("(.*)", "suffix_t1_\\1", .x))
#> Note: Using an external vector in selections is ambiguous.
#> ℹ Use `all_of(cols)` instead of `cols` to silence this message.
#> ℹ See <https://tidyselect.r-lib.org/reference/faq-external-vector.html>.

#> This message is displayed once per session.
#> # A tibble: 2 x 5
#>      id other_var rep   suffix_t1_value1 suffix_t1_value2
#>   <dbl> <chr>     <chr> <chr>            <chr>           
#> 1     1 foo       1     a                b               
#> 2     1 foo       2     c                d
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Yeah, I've got a 2 step also. "value1" and "value2" are placeholders, the values could be anything eg ("dob", "gender")...

Comment: @Paul: The longer I look into it, the less I think it possible in one step, unless you write your own `pivot_longer`function (see my updated answer).