# Adding prefix to column names generated by pivot_longer names_to .value

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

Is it possible to add a prefix to the column names that are generated from using the `.value` option in the argument `names_to` in `pivot_longer` ?

Example:

```
df <- tibble(x1 = 0.1, x2 = 0.2, y1 = 0.05, y2 = 0.15)
df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = everything(),
               names_to = c('coord_type', '.value'),
               names_pattern = '(\\D+)(\\d+)')

# A tibble: 2 × 3
  coord_type   `1`   `2`
  <chr>      <dbl> <dbl>
1 x           0.1   0.2 
2 y           0.05  0.15
```

I would like the `1` and `2` columns to have prefixes "coord_" in front of them. Of course, I could simply rename them after the pivot_longer like so:

```
df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = everything(),
               names_to = c('coord_type', '.value'),
               names_pattern = '(\\D+)(\\d+)') %>%
  rename_with(.fn = ~glue("coord_{.x}"), matches("[12]"))

# A tibble: 2 × 3
  coord_type coord_1 coord_2
  <chr>        <dbl>   <dbl>
1 x             0.1     0.2 
2 y             0.05    0.15
```

But I'm interested if `pivot_longer` has some option to do so concisely.

Comment: Looks like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67899327/how-to-attach-a-suffix-to-value-when-using-pivot-longer-and-names-patter) might help - it's about a suffix rather than a prefix, but the gist is the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could use `names_repair`, which can take a function

```
library(stringr)
library(tidyr)
pivot_longer(df, cols = everything(),
               names_to = c('coord_type', '.value'),
               names_pattern = '(\\D+)(\\d+)', 
       names_repair = ~ str_replace(.x, "^(\\d+)", "coord_\\1"))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 2 × 3
  coord_type coord_1 coord_2
  <chr>        <dbl>   <dbl>
1 x             0.1     0.2 
2 y             0.05    0.15
```